# Read data from text file and passing to function

Tags: matlab

I got a this program which takes in all it data from a .txt file. It is possible to read the required data from the text file and pass that data to a function to work with?  I have tried reading the data first and passing it to the function but then my plot refuses to work.
Right now I am doing it by sending in the name of the text file to the function and then read the data but this means that I am reading the data each time I call the function and I was hoping that I could just read the data once and then pass it on to the function. I think that not reading the data many times would speed up my program considerable.

My code looks like this

main.m

```
 young bein_AB_light.txt %%calling the function with bein_AB_light.txt as parameter.
```

young.m

```
function young(filename)

fid = fopen(filename,'r');
C = textscan(fid,'%*f%*f%*f%*f%f');
fclose(fid);

Y=10500*C{1}.^2.29; %

plot(C{1},Y,'.K')

if(strfind(filename,'AB'))
   xlabel('BMD[g/cm^3]');
   ylabel('Youngstudull');
   title('Reiknadur Youngstudull fyrir AB bein')
else
   xlabel('BMD[g/cm^3]');
   ylabel('Youngstudull');
   title('Reiknadur Youngstudull fyrir SCI bein')
end
end
```

EDIT...
This is what I was trying but it gives me error when it tries to plot. Plot does not accept filename{1} to use as the X coordinites. I have also tried to use cell2mat function to change the input but that did not work.

main.m

```
fid = fopen(filename,'r');
AB_Bein = textscan(fid,'%*f%*f%*f%*f%f');
fclose(fid);
young AB_bein %%calling the function with AB_Bein as parameter.
```

young.m

```
function young(filename)



Y=10500*filename{1}.^2.29; %

plot(filename{1},Y,'.K')

if(strfind(filename,'AB'))
   xlabel('BMD[g/cm^3]');
   ylabel('Youngstudull');
   title('Reiknadur Youngstudull fyrir AB bein')
else
   xlabel('BMD[g/cm^3]');
   ylabel('Youngstudull');
   title('Reiknadur Youngstudull fyrir SCI bein')
end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "my plot refuses to work".  Show your modified code that isn't working.

Comment: Good idea.  For help debugging the error in your new code you need to show it to us.

Comment: Add the modified code that does not work.

Comment: `function arg` almost never works, `function(arg)` almost always works. use `young(AB_bein)`. It might not matter, but `filename` is a bad name for a variable that is the contents of the file

Answer (score 1):

it's possible that your problem is the way you are calling `young`.

If I create a function

```
function fileContents= young(filename)

fid = fopen(filename,'r');
C = textscan(fid,'%*f%*f%*f%*f%f');
fclose(fid);
fileContents=C{1};
```

and then call it using

```
fileContents= young('textfile.txt');
```

rather than

```
young textfile.txt
```

That brings the data from the file out into the variable named `fileContents`